# Appearance-based methods for object detection

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Object detection can be divided into Feature-based methods and Appearance-based methods. I want to find out what the most common Appearance-based methods are for object detection. There is not much information about which are the most common approaches, therefore it would be useful to hear from someone who have experience in computer vision and object detection algorithms in particular.

Comment: What research have you done to see what kinds of object detection techniques you can find?  What techniques have you already found?  Have you read through Wikipedia?  Done some Google searching to find overviews in classes (e.g., the Stanford class on machine learning)?  Have you searched on Google Scholar?  The site works best when you exhaust all reasonable resources before asking and show us what research you've done and what you've already found in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: Community votes, please: too broad?

Comment: It is quite broad comparison or subjective opinion - it is hard to tell what is common. As Raphael suggested searching for available papers / implementations would be the best shot to answer...